# Why does str() show incorrect info for factor levels after creating a sub-matrix in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data frame in R with 274569 rows and 15 columns:

```
> str(x2)
'data.frame':   274569 obs. of  15 variables:
 $ ykod : int  99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 ...
 $ yad  : Factor w/ 43 levels "BAKUGAN","BARBIE",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ per  : Factor w/ 3 levels "2 AYLIK","3 AYLIK",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ donem: int  201106 201106 201106 201106 201106 201106 201106 201106 201106 201106 ...
 $ sayi : int  201106 201106 201106 201106 201106 201106 201106 201106 201106 201106 ...
 $ mkod : int  359 361 362 363 366 847 849 850 1505 1506 ...
 $ mad  : Factor w/ 11045 levels "    Hilal Gida           ",..: 5163 3833 10840 8284 10839 2633 10758 10293 6986 6984 ...
 $ mtip : Factor w/ 30 levels "Abone Bürosu                                      ",..: 20 20 20 20 20 2 2 2 11 11 ...
 $ kanal: Factor w/ 2 levels "OB","SS": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 ...
 $ bkod : int  110006 110006 110006 110006 110006 110006 110006 110006 110006 110006 ...
 $ bad  : Factor w/ 213 levels "4. Levent","500 Evler",..: 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 ...
 $ bolge: Factor w/ 12 levels "Adana Şehiriçi",..: 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 ...
 $ sevk : int  5 2 2 2 10 0 4 3 13 32 ...
 $ iade : int  0 2 1 2 4 0 3 2 0 8 ...
 $ satis: int  5 0 1 0 6 0 1 1 13 24 ...
```

I create a sub-matrix and display its structure:

```
> msub <- x2[x2$ykod == 99,]
> str(msub)
'data.frame':   14367 obs. of  15 variables:
 $ ykod : int  99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 ...
 $ yad  : Factor w/ 43 levels "BAKUGAN","BARBIE",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ per  : Factor w/ 3 levels "2 AYLIK","3 AYLIK",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ donem: int  201106 201106 201106 201106 201106 201106 201106 201106 201106 201106 ...
 $ sayi : int  201106 201106 201106 201106 201106 201106 201106 201106 201106 201106 ...
 $ mkod : int  359 361 362 363 366 847 849 850 1505 1506 ...
 $ mad  : Factor w/ 11045 levels "    Hilal Gida           ",..: 5163 3833 10840 8284 10839 2633 10758 10293 6986 6984 ...
 $ mtip : Factor w/ 30 levels "Abone Bürosu                                      ",..: 20 20 20 20 20 2 2 2 11 11 ...
 $ kanal: Factor w/ 2 levels "OB","SS": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 ...
 $ bkod : int  110006 110006 110006 110006 110006 110006 110006 110006 110006 110006 ...
 $ bad  : Factor w/ 213 levels "4. Levent","500 Evler",..: 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 ...
 $ bolge: Factor w/ 12 levels "Adana Şehiriçi",..: 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 ...
 $ sevk : int  5 2 2 2 10 0 4 3 13 32 ...
 $ iade : int  0 2 1 2 4 0 3 2 0 8 ...
 $ satis: int  5 0 1 0 6 0 1 1 13 24 ...
```

Now I have a sub-matrix with 14367 rows and 15 columns, but the levels of factors are still there. They should have been decreased. For example, for `yad`, there should be only one factor.

How can I *easily* make str() to show correct info for factor levels so that when I type `str(msub)` it gives me correct values?

Comment: As the answers demonstrate, `str` is in fact giving you the correct information.  However, working with factors in data.frames are often confusing.  Consider using `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in your original call to `read.table` or `read.csv` to import the data.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is expected behavior. Factor levels that have no representation in your subset do not "disappear" until you tell them to. As of recently, you can use `droplevels()`.

Comment: +1 Two others have mentioned using `factor()` as a solution - which is indeed how `droplevels.factor()` is implemented. The data frame method is a little more involved.

Answer (score 5):

In fact `str` is showing you the correct *structural* information: the factor has *the ability* to have the levels shown. Imagine concatenating two of your submatrices where one contained some of the levels and the other another set: it would be somewhat of a hassle to merge this! This is simply how factors work in R.

If you want to know which factors are 'present' in your data, one of the options is using `table` to count the occurrences.

If you want your factor reduced, so it only contains the levels that are actually present, you can reapply factor to it:

```
myfact<-factor(rep(1:2,5), levels=1:3, labels=letters[1:3])
myfact
# [1] a b a b a b a b a b
#Levels: a b c
factor(myfact)
# [1] a b a b a b a b a b
#Levels: a b
```

You can simply apply this to all the factor columns of your data.frame to get what you say you want.

Answer (score 1):

The levels of the factor are part of the column, and not dependant on the levels actually present:

```
> x <- factor(LETTERS[1:10])
> x
 [1] A B C D E F G H I J
Levels: A B C D E F G H I J
> y <- x[1]
> y
[1] A
Levels: A B C D E F G H I J
> factor(y)
[1] A
Levels: A
>
```

I am sure, there is another way, but this should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
x <- factor(LETTERS[1:10])
y <- x[1, drop=TRUE]
y
```